# Extremely slow read speed on hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, smartctl

I have a 4TB hard disk on a NAS which I only use to store media files and play them from there using my local network. Its about 50% filled. It worked fine for for years but I recently noticed that some files were failing to play properly. By that I mean the file takes a long time to start playing and then gets stuck after a few seconds for a while, then continues playing for a few more seconds and gets stuck again etc. When I tried to copy the file to play it locally, the speed was about 300 to 800 KB/s over a wired network. Other files were copyed at 30-40MB/s, so no network failure.

I checked the drive using smartctl:

```
smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [aarch64-linux-6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-v8] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

And more detailed...

```
smartctl -A /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [aarch64-linux-6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-v8] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   198   198   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       55877
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   181   175   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7941
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   079   079   000    Old_age   Always       -       21386
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   058   058   000    Old_age   Always       -       31113
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       19183
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   182   182   000    Old_age   Always       -       14056
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       849904
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   121   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   132   132   000    Old_age   Offline      -       27533
```

And the values seems to be mostly fine?

Finaly I tried executing

```
fsck -p
```

on the drive and after several hours (18-20?) it reported no bad blocks and no failures at all. Im a bit at a loss at this point. Is the drive about to fail? Is there anything I should try before getting a new drive?

Comment: Rather than **fsck**, a more exhaustive read test would be the SMART extended (aka long) test. The `Current_Pending_Sector` raw value is concerning.

Comment: Raw_Read_Error_Rate  means for every failure the drive has to read that sector again, possibly several times and that slows down the read/write speeds.  I would just replace the drive.

Comment: A nonzero `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` raw value may not be reason for concern. At least one vendor (Seagate) stores two values (number of errors & number of reads) in that one word; so a non-zero raw value for a `rate` is always likely.